# In Objective-C, how does +alloc know how much memory to allocate?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Let's say I have a class declared as:

```
@class SomeClass

@interface SomeClass: NSObject {
  NSString *myString;
  NSString *yourString;
}

@end
```

And later, in some other code I say:

```
SomeClass *myClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

How does SomeClass know how much memory to allocate given that it didn't override +alloc?  Presumably it needs storage for the ivars myString and yourString, but it's using +alloc inherited from NSObject.  Is there reference material that covers these details?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`+alloc` is just a class method like any other.  The default implementation in NSObject, uses `class_getInstanceSize()` to get the instance size that should be allocated.   The instance size is determined based upon a combination of per-class (without inheritance) compile time structure size and per-runtime calculation of total size of the class and all superclasses.  This is how non-fragile iVars are possible in 64 bit and the iPhone runtimes.

Some classes, class clusters in particular, don't actually do the true instance allocation until the initializer is called (which is why it is important to do `self = [super init]` in your initializer methods).

Comment: What are class clusters?  Is this an Objective-C term I should be more familiar with?

Comment: NSString is a class cluster, for example.  When you create an NSString, you actually get an instance of whatever subclass is optimized to handle that particular type of string.

Answer (score 4):

`+[NSObject alloc]` resolves to a call to the Objective-C runtime, which knows the size of each class.

Answer (score 4):

Mike Ash wrote an article describing how some of this works:

[Friday Q&A 2009-03-13: Intro to the Objective-C Runtime](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-13-intro-to-the-objective-c-runtime.html)

Answer (score -2):

The `alloc` method does the equivalent of `sizeof` when it goes to create a new object.  Also, the `myString` and `yourString` instance variables don't really have too much storage: they are merely pointers, so `alloc` just allocates enough memory to hold the addresses.

Comment: It does not;  sizeof is a compile time only operation.  Allocation size is determined at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, myString and yourString don't have too much storage, but they have some, and it's significant, and it has to be allocated somewhere.

Comment: myString and yourString are both exactly the size of a pointer in SomeClass.

Comment: @bbum, I know, I was replying to Quartz.

Comment: I know that `sizeof` is a compile-time operation; Objective-C performs a check *similar* to `sizeof`.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't.  The size of the class's instances are determined at compile time. The modern ABI, though, allows a superclass to change size without breaking subclasses, requiring a bit of at-launch calculation.  Finally, the class can dynamically resize instances at allocation as needed (see NSData and NSString).

Comment: @bbum, `sizeof` is not just a compile time only operation. If it is used on a variable length array (as permitted by C99), then it must return the size of that variable length array, and in many cases,  can only known at runtime.