# Is there ever a need for a class to override +alloc in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Based on some answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371190/in-objective-c-how-does-alloc-know-how-much-memory-to-allocate) it appears that +alloc does some behind-the-scenes magic to allocate memory for an instance of an object in Objective-C.  Is there ever a need to override +alloc?

Comment: What Ken said.  But... to emphasize... it is exceedingly rare to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite rare.

NSString is an example of a class that overrides +alloc as an implementation detail.  If you were to check, you'd find +[NSString alloc] returns something of class NSPlaceholderString.  This is part of the implementation of the string [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34).

You could also override to allocate from a different allocation NSZone be default.  Or, you can play tricks like calling [NSAllocateObject](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSAllocateObject) with something non-zero for `extraBytes` to provide a dynamic amount of space following your ivars.  For example, you might think that the private subclass of NSString that you normally end up would look something like this:

```
@interface {
    NSUInteger length;
    unichar *data;
}
```

but that isn't the case.  It's a single block of memory that contains both the length and the character data.  Different NSString instances are different size blocks of memory.  This is the kind of thing you can arrange by calling NSAllocateObject directly.

But all of these things are tricks and hacks.  If you override +alloc, something special is going on.

Answer (score 4):

`+alloc` is not doing any magic, it is just calling a method in the Objective-C runtime to get the size of a class instance and allocating that amount of memory. You may want to override `+alloc` when writing a true singleton (i.e. you want to guarantee that only a single instance of your class can ever be allocated). Although it's rarely necessary to go to these lengths when writing a singleton class, you could. In general you would override `+alloc` to provide alternative (like not allocating memory in a different zone, allocating a different class than the receiving class--this is what class clusters might do) behavior or you might call `+[super alloc]` to do the standard work then add your own customizations.

Answer (score 1):

I override alloc for Singleton classes, e.g.:

```
#import "Singleton.h"

static Singleton * instance;

@implementation Singleton

+ (void)initialize
{
    if (!instance) {
        instance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone * const)notUsed
{
    return instance;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is generally not a proper way to do it, because you misinform users who write `[Singleton new]` that they won't get a new instance. In fact, the instance got `init`-ed twice instead of once. Instead you should just expose a `+(instancetype)sharedInstance;`class method. And protecting `allocWithZone:` will not protect you from a user using runtime functions to instantiate multiple instances.